# How can I get PHP8 with OCI8 to connect to a remote Oracle database using oci_connect from inside a Docker container?

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, php-8, oci8

I have a vanilla PHP Docker container with Oracle Instant Client installed, and the `oci8` extension installed and added to the php ini.

I have a pretty bland php script to test the `oci_connect` method:

`$connection = oci_connect($dbCredentials['dbUser'], $dbCredentials['dbPass'], $connectString);`

This works as expected from *outside* the container, but is throwing a timeout from within the container:

`ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

I suspect there's something in the networking between the container and my local, any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Open the port 1521 (or whatever you use) when you start the container?  Use a user-defined docker network? This may have some tips: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-2-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python

Comment: Thx @ChristopherJones - I am opening up 1521 in the docker compose yaml (1521:1521)

Comment: @ChristopherJones could this be a limitation of my host? I'm using an M1 Mac, and from https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/,  the "host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac"

Comment: Shouldn't be.  I connect from M1 host to a DB container, from containers to containers, from containers to remote DBs.

Comment: Thx for the update @ChristopherJones - I'll keep digging. What docker image are you using for the container for the connection going container -> remote db? and are you connecting using PHP?

Comment: Mostly Oracle Linux but it is personal preference.